# RSA Archer: How to execute a Data Feed from an Application

Tags: c#, datafeed, rsa-archer-grc

I'm working on the RSA Archer GRC platform (ver 5.4). I have a data feed that i want to execute without the need to access to the platform. This execution will be requested from an application (or maybe an Internet Explorer Extension) written in C#.

I've been checking the Archer APIs, but aside from authentication functions to log in an user from the app, nothing else seems suitable for this job. So i'm wondering if this is even possible for the Archer platform.

I've seen the functions to create and update records, but that would be like doing all the job that the data feed already does, that's why i'm looking for a way to execute it, rather than reconstruct the whole data feed procedure.

Thanks for your time!

EDIT: Well, after a while i finally found the up-to-date Archer API reference  and it does have a ["data feed" set of functions](https://vendor.ironmountain.com/Archer/Help/en/HTML-Help/Content/Platform/_API_Rest/PDF%20Pages/restapi_ch_4.htm). Nevertheless, the [Archer 5.4 REST API Reference](https://community.rsa.com/docs/DOC-18709) does not have this set of functions. That would mean that i would have to check if those functions are available for the platform version the app will be connecting to.

Any more info about the matter would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those functions were released in version 5.5 SP4.
[5.5 SP4 REST API Guide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBPuX.png)

Comment: Thank you. Could you provide a link for the API Reference?

RSA has a horrible archive organization, and i can't find their 5.5 SP4 REST API Reference, only SP3, and the 5.5 alone doesn't have these functions.

Comment: If you're apart of the RSA Link Community, everything 5.5 SP$ is located here. https://community.rsa.com/docs/DOC-41227

The specific REST API Reference Guide is located here: https://community.rsa.com/docs/DOC-41230. Download the .zip file and then extract. Navigate into until you come across 'GRCPlatform_5_5_SP4_RESTAPI_Reference_Guide_ClicktoStart.htm and use that file to launch the web guide.

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much. I already voted you, but it seems it won't be public until i get 15 rep.